# How is SpaCy's similarity computed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, spacy

Beginner NLP Question here:

## How does the .similiarity method work?

Wow spaCy is great! Its tfidf model could be easier to preprocess, but w2v with only one line of code (token.vector)?! - Awesome!

In his  [10 line tutorial on spaCy](https://github.com/cytora/pycon-nlp-in-10-lines/blob/master/00_spacy_intro.ipynb) andrazhribernik show's us the .similarity method that can be run on tokens, sents, word chunks, and docs.

After `nlp = spacy.load('en')` and `doc = nlp(raw_text)`
we can do .similarity queries between tokens and chunks.
However, what is being calculated behind the scenes in this `.similarity` method?

SpaCy already has the incredibly simple `.vector`, which computes the w2v vector as trained from the GloVe model (how cool would a `.tfidf` or `.fasttext` method be?).

Is the model similarity model simply computing the cosine similarity between these two w2v-GloVe-vectors or doing something else? The specifics aren't clear in the [documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities); any help appreciated!

Comment: Update: As of v2.0.1.0 its super easy to load in other pretrained vectors (e.g. Facebook's FastText). Thanks spaCy guys! https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#custom-loading-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the method you are referring to is the token similarity one, you can find the function in the sourcecode [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/9003fd25e5e966bd8d1b67a18f3ebd6010d6f718/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L106). As you can see it computes the cosine similarity between the vectors.

As it says in the tutorial:

> A word embedding is a representation of a word, and by extension a whole language corpus, in a vector or other form of numerical mapping. This allows words to be treated numerically with word similarity represented as spatial difference in the dimensions of the word embedding mapping.

So the vector distance can be related to the word similarity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to - thanks! My question is more: How are these 'vectors' computed? Is it just using the same GloVe word2vec model that token.vector uses? I'm thinking the answer is yes, because I can't find mention of any other vectorization method for word embedding (e.g. bag of words or tfidf).

Comment: So by default it loads vectors for one-million English words computed with the GloVe algorithm. You could compute your own vector representations for a dictionary of words and load them with vocab.load_vectors().

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, in short, it's yes:

[Link to Souce Code](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities)

```
return numpy.dot(self.vector, other.vector) / (self.vector_norm * other.vector_norm)
```

This looks like its the formula for computing [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition) and the vectors seem to be created with SpaCy's `.vector` which documentation says is trained from GloVe's w2v model.