# Spacy similarity function

Tags: python, similarity, spacy

I'm trying to use Spacy Library for sentences similarity, and I want to understand how it's work!?

Their documentation is not clear:

> By default, spaCy uses an average-of-vectors algorithm, using
>   pre-trained vectors if available (e.g. the en_core_web_lg model). If
>   not, the doc.tensor attribute is used, which is produced by the
>   tagger, parser and entity recognizer. This is how the en_core_web_sm
>   model provides similarities. Usually the .tensor-based similarities
>   will be more structural, while the word vector similarities will be
>   more topical. You can also customize the .similarity() method, to
>   provide your own similarity function, which can be trained using
>   supervised techniques.

I found this question :[How does the .similiarity method works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348209/how-is-spacys-similarity-computed) that says it uses word embeddings, but in my implementation I don't have a "en_core_web_lg model" but I have the en_core_web_sm, so in this way how is the similarity computed by "tagger, parser and entity recognizer" ?

Answer (score 2):

With a closer look in the documentation I think that you can find what you are searching for.

First of all, a doc object contains a lot of tokens. The vector for the doc is the average of the vectors of the tokens.

Now, what is the vector of a token? If you use an `md` or `lg` model, that means that the `token.vec` gives you the token vector, which is actually a gloVe vector. If you are using an `sm` model, then the documentation says that this vector contains structural information. That means that tokens which have the same PoS tag and similar DEP behavior will have higher similarity scores than other tokens, even if their semantics are quite different.

A general comment would be not to use the similarity method for `sm` models if you are not intending to get you semantics with this because most probably you will get inaccurate results.